# What expect when cross processing in ECP-2d developer?

Tags: cross-processing

I found some fresh ECP(-2d) chemistry rather cheap, and was wondering if anyone knew what to expect when cross processing C-41, E6 or ECN film in ECP (-2d) chemistry.

Comment: Anytime one cross processes film using a chemistry previously untried with a particular film emulsion, the only thing one can expect for sure is the unexpected.

Comment: @MichaelC True. However it may be possible that someone here has tried it, or perhaps read some further info which I was not able to find when I did a Google for it.